# pandas dataframe can't specify list value to column

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to assign a list value to a column with the following code

```
   In [105] df[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349]['tags'].head()

  Out [105] 4       NaN
            2035    NaN
            2630    NaN
            3085    NaN
            6833    NaN
            Name: tags, dtype: object

   In [106] tags

  Out [106] ['자연공원', '도심상점']

   In [107] df.loc[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349,'tags'] = pd.Series(tags)

   In [108] df[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349]['tags'].head()

  Out [108] 4       NaN
            2035    NaN
            2630    NaN
            3085    NaN
            6833    NaN
            Name: tags, dtype: object

   In [109]
```

So why is value not being assigned?

*Edit

So it seems, I can do something like

```
df.loc[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349,'tags'] = pd.Series([tags] * len(df))
```

why not ?

```
df.loc[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349,'tags'] = pd.Series([tags] * len(df[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349]))
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason here is `pandas` will check the `index` as well when you create the new series, (The index is range index from 0 to n-1)then index is mismatched with assign position, so `pandas` will return NaN

```
df.loc[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349,'tags'] = pd.Series([tags] * len(df[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349]), index = df.index[df['review_meta_id'] == 5349] )
```

Comment: so it means `pd.Series([tags])` is a fine solution as it is I guess?

Comment: @eugene yep~//./